# row_number() gives a non-obvious result

Tags: r, dataframe

```
b.set <- 1
df <- data.frame (co = c(2.3,3.1,5.7), factor = c(3,5,6))%>% 
  mutate (a = 1,
          b = ifelse (b.set == 1, row_number()+10-1, 0),
  )
```

I get the following result:

```
   co factor a  b
1 2.3      3 1 10
2 3.1      5 1 10
3 5.7      6 1 10
```

I would like the end result to be as follows

```
   co factor a  b
1 2.3      3 1 10
2 3.1      5 1 11
3 5.7      6 1 12
```

I'm pretty sure it worked fine yesterday.

Comment: the length of b.set is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we need `if/else` as `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same length - `b.set` is of length 1, where as the 'yes' is of length 3

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame (co = c(2.3,3.1,5.7), factor = c(3,5,6))%>%
     mutate(a = 1, b = if(b.set == 1) row_number() + 10 -1 else 0)
```

-output

```
   co factor a  b
1 2.3      3 1 10
2 3.1      5 1 11
3 5.7      6 1 12
```